# Add the frequencies based on match between two existing columns from two dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframe **df1** and **df2**

```
df1=data.frame(species=c("Natica", "Turritela", "Anadara", "Arca", "Murex", "Tellina"),
freq=c(20,2,5,40,12,3))

df2=data.frame(species=c("Natica","Tellina"),freq=c(12,2))
```

I want to add the freq value of df2 to df1 only when the first column of df1 matches df2

So I am expecting an output like this:

my df1 should give the following output:

```
        species     freq
   1    Natica        32
   2    Tureitella     2
   3    Anadara        5
   4    Arca          40
   5    Murex         12
   6    Tellina        5
```

Comment: `library(dplyr); full_join(df1,df2) %>% group_by(species) %>% summarize(sum(freq))`

Comment: showing this: Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: try `install.packages("dplyr"); library(dplyr)`

Comment: I am having trouble in installing the package, I am using R 3.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is the following: 
This works as long as all values of `df2` are contained in `df1` and does not require a package.

```
df1[!is.na(match(df1$species,df2$species)),]$freq <- df1[!is.na(match(df1$species,df2$species)),]$freq + df2$freq
> df1
    species freq
1    Natica   32
2 Turritela    2
3   Anadara    5
4      Arca   40
5     Murex   12
6   Tellina    5
```